# How to return admin emails in SpringBoot as a List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Users can have multiple roles. But how can I return all admin users with a List? I tried a similar solution but he had it different compared to mine

USE request_manager; SELECT `users`.`username` FROM `request_manager`.`users` JOIN users_roles ON users.id=users_roles.user_id  WHERE role_id=2;

This query will return what I need in SQL but I don't know how to make it return it here in springboot. I
If there is another better method, I'd be glad to know.

User.java (entity)

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String username;

private String password;

private String name;

private String surname;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@ToString.Exclude
private List<RequestEntity> requestEntities;


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
    User user = (User) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public void addRole(Role role) {
    this.roles.add(role);
}}
```

Role.java (entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")

public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
private String name;

public Role() { }

public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Role(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Role(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}}
```

UserRepository.java (repo)

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?1")
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Hi, by "returning a list" do you mean you need it to be in a REST Get request response ? @John555

Comment: No I need it to return a list before the POST request so I can send the email to administrators only when a request is posted

Comment: List<User> findAllByRoles (EnterCodeHere); I kinda need to add smth like this in the Repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
    List<User> findAllByRole_Id(Integer roleId);
}
```

Comment: `List<String> adminEmails1(){
List<User> admins = userRepository.findAllByRoles_Id(2);
List<String> adminEmails = new ArrayList<>();
for (User user:admins) {
            adminEmails.add(user.getUsername());
        }
        adminEmails.forEach(System.out::println);

        return adminEmails;
    }`

Is this supposed to work? Added a test before the end but I still get error
"Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [com.example.project.database.entity.Role"

Comment: becaue you are giving Role not RoleId in : findAllByRoles(2)

Comment: change it to findAllByRole_Id

Comment: Ok I did it but this is what i get now:
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.project.database.repository.UserRepository.findAllByRole_Id(java.lang.Integer)! No property role found for type User! Did you mean 'roles'?

Maybe I need to add this to the roles Repository?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after I changed it to 
List<User> findAllByRoles_Id(Integer roles_id); and it worked flawlessly. God bless you

Comment: String[] adminEmails1(){

        List<User> admins = userRepository.findAllByRoles_Id(2);
        List<String> adminEmails = new ArrayList<>();


        for (User user:admins) {
            adminEmails.add(user.getUsername());
        }

        String[] stringArray = new String[adminEmails.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < adminEmails.size(); i++) {
            stringArray[i] = adminEmails.get(i);
        }
        return stringArray;
    }

Here's how I converted it to a String in case anybody needs it

Comment: I am happy to hear that it worked.